# Drupal HybridAuth Use Graph API

Tags: 7, authentication-authorization

I successfully setup [hybridauth](https://drupal.org/project/hybridauth) module with drupal & it works fine. Now I want to fetch some details of logged in user.

There is a documentation on doing this using graph api [here](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/userguide/Access_IDps_APIs.html). However, when I try this in a drupal module its not working. What is the right way to interact with the module?

```
 $facebook = $hybridauth->authenticate( "Facebook" );
 $response = $facebook->api()->api('/me/friends');
```

Below is the error returned.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function authenticate() on a non-object in /var/www/html/dev/shophoc/v1/sites/all/modules/shophoc/shophoc.module on line 4
```